# Amex personal savings

Tags: united-states, non-resident, germany, form-w-8-ben

I opened Amex personal savings when I lived in U.S. with U.S visa.
But now I moved to Germany due to my job and no longer live in U.S.

For TAX reason, Do I need to send W-8 BEN form to Amex national bank?
If so, Do I need to inform that I live in Germany before I send W-8 BEN?

I checked their website but there was no instruction about this.